# How long will it take to migrate a 5 GB Database to Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-rds, migration

I just need an estimation.

How long will / can it take to move a 5 GB big database from an external source to amazon RDS. What is best practise to do it?

I just moved succesfully a few days ago a small test database (wordpress) from an external webhost to amazon. But without compression etc.

I`d say it would take 4-5 hours to move a 5 GB database, but I have not so much experience and I am unsure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual answer: It depends

I'm assuming that you've read this guide on how to import data into an Oracle RDS (I chose Oracle because it's what I know, and you don't say what instance type you're using): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html

There's similar guides for MySQL: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html

Have a look at the guides and do some tests, they should provide you with some idea of timescales.

Comment: Yeah I know that it depends, thanks for you references, but I am talking about like: would it take 4-5 hours, 10 minutes, a few days or even more?

Comment: As @phil-summer said, you have to make your benchmarks in order to get the order of magnitude of this task. The schema, the type of data that you have, but also your own upload link bandwidth must be taken into account.
Did you check the time that it took to import your test database? That may be used as a benchmark.

Comment: @Roman We can't tell you how long it will take. I can tell you how long it took me to transport and duplicate a 50GB database into an Oracle instance running on an m4.2xl EC2 instance in AWS with the data going to a 500GB non-PIOPS volume, transferred using a 100MB/s link to AWS.  Notice the level of detail I provided there?  If you provided the same, we might possibly be able to help provide rough estimates.  Without it... no chance.  Do your own testing at scale.  Try it out.